# Danger does not warn when check should fail

Tags: git, pull-request, danger

I'm using Danger to check the PRs.
My Dangerfile contains:

```
# Alert if we are pointing to a debug SDK version
if git.modified_files.include?("tutorials/sdk-refapp/build.gradle")
  diff = git.diff_for_file("tutorials/sdk-refapp/build.gradle")
  fail("Please ensure you are not pointing to a debug SDK version in the sdk-refapp after QA approval", sticky: true) if (diff && diff.patch.include?('-debug'))
end
```

The PR contains the change:

```
-def SK_SDK_VERSION = ""
-
+def version = ""
+def SK_SDK_VERSION = "$version-debug"
```

when I call `danger local` I don't see the warning I'm expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. If instead of `danger local` I use `danger pr <url>` then everything works. `danger local` was pointing to the wrong PR for a reason I don't know.